# Advice needed on closing own question, accepting valid answer or deleting

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question, accepted-answer, self-delete

I'm needing a little advice. I recently [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821034/is-storing-card-details-without-the-permission-of-the-card-holder-against-pci-ds) on Stack Overflow. After posting it I realised that SO probably isn't the best place for it, but by then deleting it I think would have been rude as I already had a comment, so I chose to close the question; it seems two other votes agree with me. However, I have since been given a valid answer, so what is the correct action here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best course of action is probably to flag it for migration to [Sec.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/)